# How to sort DataFrame and show it in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"car":["mazda", "audi", "audi", "bmw", "mazda"], "price":[10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000]})
```

And now by using my code below I acheived in columns: car, mean, min, max price, but I want to have 1 column more in this table which will show me position of car in this table sorted by mean, and I want to have it ascending so from the lowest to the biggest mean price.

```
data.groupby("car").agg({"price":[np.mean, min, max]})
```

This new column (if it is possible) I would like to have between car and mean.

Comment: What is your goal, do you want to sort your data, or create a new column which shows the rank of the means?

Comment: by using second code I made table which shows car and mean min max, and I want to see also one more column wich will sorted this tablem by mean from the lowest to the biggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, its better to create your groupby dataframe like this, to prevent `MultiIndex`:

```
dfg = data.groupby("car")['price'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max'])
```

Then to create a rank column, use `Series.rank`:

```
dfg['rank'] = dfg['mean'].rank().astype(int)

        mean    min    max  rank
car                             
audi   25000  20000  30000     1
bmw    40000  40000  40000     3
mazda  30000  10000  50000     2
```

Finally to sort, use `DataFrame.sort_values`:

```
dfg = dfg.sort_values('mean', ascending=False)

        mean    min    max  rank
car                             
bmw    40000  40000  40000     3
mazda  30000  10000  50000     2
audi   25000  20000  30000     1
```

I think you just want to `sort_values`.

Comment: perfect ! but how can I sort descending, so from the biggest mean to the lowest ?

Comment: Use ascending=False key in sort_values method

Answer (score 1):

Here is full solution for your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({"car":["mazda", "audi", "audi", "bmw", "mazda"], "price":[10000, 20000, 30000, 40000, 50000]})
data = data.groupby("car").agg({"price":[np.mean, min, max]})
data = data.sort_values(by=('price', 'mean'))
data.insert(1,('price','rank'), range(1,data.shape[0]+1))
```

Result:

```
    price
    mean    rank    min     max
car                 
audi    25000   1   20000   30000
mazda   30000   2   10000   50000
bmw     40000   3   40000   40000
```

But it's not optimal, may be you don't need 2-level index for columns and my ranking method is not optimal. Other solutions better in something.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to get is a new column showing a rank using the means, I would do the following:

```
data.sort_values(by=['price'])
data.insert(1,"Price Rank", data.index)
```

The idea is that first you sort by prices, and then you insert the index as a column for ranking.

Comment: This will fail, since OP created a dataframe after the groupby.

Comment: you do not understand, this code made some table, data.groupby("car").agg({"price":[np.mean, min, max]}) and please change me this code so as to sort price by mean and show this ranking in this table

Comment: Yes, this should be done on the dataframe created by the groupby command